# Creating a function in-memory and calling it

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I have a simple 'function', if you could even call it that, which is solely a 'NOP' stored in memory:

```
byte[] func = new byte[] {0x90}; // NOP
```

I then allocate a piece of memory which is going to hold it, and set the contents:

```
Memory mem = new Memory(func.length);
mem.write(0, code, 0, code.length); // Write all bytes from code, starting at mem + 0
```

Now, I want to 'call' this little function I have just created. Let us try:

```
Function function = Function.getFunction(mem, Function.C_CONVENTION);
function.invokeVoid(null); // I have tried other types of invokeXX too.
```

But that does not work, but instead throws an exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:367)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:268)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeVoid(Function.java:727)
    at [my line calling invokeVoid]`

I had not expected to receive that error because it certainly should be there. I have no idea what could possibly go wrong.

Is there anything I am missing here or (obviously, but what?) doing wrong?

*NB: I am using JNA 4.1.0.*

Comment: On most CPUs these days, code (read-only) and data (writable) are on separate pages.  I don't think you can run code in data pages this way.  BTW using generated byte code is more likely to be work, and could be faster.

Comment: Well, I too was not aware but according to the examples [here](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), it is suggested to be all good to generate functions on the fly and call those. That's what I was attempting too. :)

Comment: Are you sure it's not just executing your NOP then proceeding to some undefined memory after that? You may just need a call return opcode.

Comment: @darron the code still does crash the same style with: 
`asm.push(Asm.ebp);
asm.mov(Asm.ebp, Asm.esp);
asm.nop();
asm.pop(Asm.ebp);
asm.ret();`
Note that I use a code generation library. The output is valid, I have checked it against x86 instruction tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think using Memory object is not a good idea. If you look at the finalize method you will notice that it calls the native free() function and providing address which is not managed by the jvm may cause segmentation fault. Obviously here the problem appears earlier. Try to provide a Pointer object to the Function.getFunction but not Memory.
You can simply try this:

```
Pointer ptr = Pointer.createConstant(0x90);
Function f = Function.getFunction(ptr, Function.C_CONVENTION);
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that, as Peter Lawrey had suggested, the page was indeed protected from execution. The solution was rather simple.

I had to map VirtualProtectEx from the Win32 API and call that with a value of 0x40 to allow execution. After that was done, it worked!